# Update state of a react component when language is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have created a custom table component I forked from ant design. I reuse it in all my components, It takes an array of all columns and renders it. I pass columns as a prop called initialColumns.

My issue is whenever the user changes the language, the table contents is re rendering but not the columns which I passed, they don't get translated, How would I force a rerender when the language is changed.

**custom table component**

```
const TableComponent = (props) => {
const { initialColumns, dataSource, handleClick } = props
return ( <Table
            columns={colmenu.visibleColumns}
            dataSource={dataSource}
            size="small"
            pagination={{
              pageSizeOptions: ['10', '20', '50'],
              showSizeChanger: true,
            }}
          />)
}
```

**Parent component, here I call my TableComponent as pass it columns**

It looks something like this:

```
 const columns = [
    {
      title: t.status,
      dataIndex: 'status',
      key: 'status',
      sorter: (a, b) => a.status.localeCompare(b.status),
      ...GetColumnSearchProps(['status']),
      className: 'text-center',
      checked: true,
    },
.
.
.
.
```

here is how I get the translated files

const { messages: t } = useIntl()

and this is the render method:

```
  <TableComponent
            initialColumns={columns}
            dataSource={data}
            handleClick={addModal}
            title="AABC"
          />
```

So how would I update the initialColumns prop when the language is changed?

Comment: How is the language changed? Is this something the React app knows about? Is it stored in some state in the app?

Comment: thank you for the reply, Yes the react app knows about it I am using redux saga.

Comment: Thanks. Would you be so kind as to update your question to include how your UI code would access this redux state? I'm assuming you are still using the `connect` HOC or newer `useSelector` hook to pull it?